# Installing R package Rwofost gives RcppModule.cpp:10:30: fatal error: R_interface_util.h:

Tags: r, installation, package, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to install the Rwofost R package on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS using the following command

```
 install.packages("Rwofost", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

However it throws the following error:

> RcppModule.cpp:10:30: fatal error: R_interface_util.h: No such file or
>   directory compilation terminated. /usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:168: recipe
>   for target 'RcppModule.o' failed make: *** [RcppModule.o] Error 1
>   ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rwofost’
>   * removing ‘/home/yaseen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rwofost’

Wondering how to install Rwofost?

Comment: Do you have `Rcpp` installed?

Answer (score 2):

You need to talk to the maintainer -- it looks like that that missing file `R_interface_util.h` is a file of his which is not included, so the build fails.

As the filename is somewhat unique, we can [search for the file on GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=R_interface_util.h&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) which suggests it really is a file by that author or team.